# Multiple Brackets in Chemfig Polymer - Cannot Get Rid of Errors

Tags: chemfig

I am struggling to get a Reaktion showing a Polymerisation Process using `chemfig` right.

This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-\lewis{0.,C}(-[2])(-[6])}
\+
\chemfig{[@{left,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])=C(-[2])(-[6])[@{right,0.5}]}
%\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 40pt, indice = n]{left}{right}
\arrow
\chemfig{R-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{left,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{right,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])-\lewis{0.,C}(-[2])(-[6])}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 40pt, indice = n]{left}{right}
\schemestop
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

This is the current result:

[image]

For some reason the second bracket is the way I want it, but the first one is not. It seems as if it is not getting the specifications made by `\polymerdelim`, so I thought I might need to add the line also to the `\chemfig` above.

If I activate the line

```
%\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 40pt, indice = n]{left}{right}
```

I get this error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named left is known.See the pgf package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \chemfig
```

Can someone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: You do not need a pair of beginning and ending bonds in `\chemfig{[@{left,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])=C(-[2])(-[6])[@{right,0.5}]}` so that it looks like `\chemfig{-C(...)=C(...)-}, do you?

Comment: Also, please provide a complete example (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) instead of code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `chemfig`, Section 13, the syntax `@{<name>, <coeff>}` can only be used at the beginning of the optional argument of a bond. In the second `\chemfig` of your example

```
\chemfig{[@{left,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])=C(-[2])(-[6])[@{right,0.5}]}
```

optional arguments `[@{left,0.5}]` and `[@{right,0.5}]` has no corresponding bonds, hence the nodes `left` and `right` are never created.

#### Option 1

If you are ok with beginning and ending bonds, then use

```
\chemfig{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[@{left,0.5}4])=C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{right,0.5}]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n]{left}{right}
```

[image]

#### Option 2

If you want to keep the bond-less style, you can use `@{<name>}<atom>` to add a node to an atom, and use `\polymerdelim` options `open xshift` and `close xshift` to adjust the position of delimiters. Note in this case, the left and right space is not auto-adjusted.

```
\chemfig{@{left}C(-[2])(-[6])=@{right}C(-[2])(-[6])}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n, 
  open xshift=-8pt, close xshift=]{left}{right}
```

[image]

#### Option 3

This is a variant of option 1, in which the beginning and ending bonds are specified but not drawn (by bond option `[,,,draw=none]`). To get better horizontal spacing, those two bonds are also shortened (by bond option `[,0.5,,,]) and the position of nodes are adjusted (from` @{left, 0.5}`to`@{left, 1}`).

```
\chemfig{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[@{left,1}4,.5,,,draw=none])=C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{right,1},.5,,,draw=none]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n]{left}{right}
```

[image]

Full example:

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{R-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-\lewis{0.,C}(-[2])(-[6])}
  \+
  %% option 1
  % \chemfig{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[@{left,0.5}4])=C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{right,0.5}]}
  % \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n]{left}{right}
  %
  %% option 2
  % \chemfig{@{left}C(-[2])(-[6])=@{right}C(-[2])(-[6])}
  % \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n, 
  %   open xshift=-8pt, close xshift=]{left}{right}
  %% option 3
  \chemfig{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[@{left,1}4,.5,,,draw=none])=C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{right,1},.5,,,draw=none]}
  \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n]{left}{right}
  \arrow
  \chemfig{R-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{left,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6])-[@{right,0.5}]C(-[2])(-[6])-\lewis{0.,C}(-[2])(-[6])}
  \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height=40pt, depth=, indice=n]{left}{right}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]